# Possibility of the cellular decomposition of a manifold

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology

I am working to find if it's possible to find a cellular decomposition of $S^2\times S^1$ as following: $e^0\cup e^1\cup e_1^2\cup e_2^2\cup e^3$.

I cannot find such a decomposition. And I try to compute the cohomology group of it to get a contradiction, but it seems not to work.

Anyone has some ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with a very simple Euler characteristic argument, but if you wish, you can do it using cellular homology, since you know what the cellular chain complex (corresponding to this structure) looks like:

$$
C_3= \mathbb Z \stackrel 0 \to \mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z \stackrel \psi \to \mathbb Z \stackrel 0 \to \mathbb Z
$$

know you know $im \psi =0$ and $\ker \psi \cong \mathbb Z$ which gives a contradiction

Comment: How can we get that $C_3\to C_2$ is zero?

Comment: Since $S^2\times S^1$ is orientable, then $H_n(S^2\times S^1)\cong \mathbb Z$. Got it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use the Euler characteristic: $\chi(S^2 \times S^1) = \chi(S^2) \cdot \underbrace{\chi(S^1)}_{=0} = 0$, but if you had a decomposition like you said you would get a characteristic of $1-1+2-1 = 1 \neq 0$.